# spring security login always ends with failure url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with proper configuration of spring security, registering works well, restricting access works well but when it comes to logging I get always a failure url result, can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Here is my SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/manage/**").hasAuthority("USER").antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/business_login").permitAll().antMatchers("/business_password_recovery").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/business_register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/business_login").defaultSuccessUrl("/manage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/process_business_login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .failureUrl("/business_login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/templates/**",
            "/boomerang/**");
}

}
```

this is my login form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="form-default" method="POST" role="form" action="/process_business_login">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group login-form-input">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="email"
                                                class="form-control form-control-lg login-form-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                            <input type="password" name="password"
                                                placeholder="password"
                                                class="form-control form-control-lg login-form-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="checkbox danger-checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkRemember"> <label
                                                class="light-gray-color" for="chkRemember">Remember
                                                me</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-styled btn-lg btn-block btn-danger mt-4 no-border-radius danger-button-login">LOG
                                    IN</button>
                            </form>
```

Right there you can see a part of my application.properties file, here I define queries for spring security, they look like this:

```
    spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from business_user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from business_user u inner join user_role ur on(u.id_business_user=ur.id_business_user) inner join role r on(ur.id_role=r.id_role) where u.email=?
```

The login always redirects to failure url site, where do I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration states

```
.usernameParameter("email")
```

but the parameter *name* from the login form states:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="email"
       class="form-control form-control-lg login-form-input">
```

So there is a mismatch. I'm thinking that you want to name your form correctly, 
instead of

```
name="username"
```

you have

```
name="email"
```

or you change your configuration from

```
.usernameParameter("email")
```

to

```
 .usernameParameter("username")
```

or remove it, since `.usernameParameter("username")` is the default.

Comment: Thank you man, this was it, such a typos are sometimes so hard to find :D